# Create mixin with nth-child

Tags: css, less, css-selectors

I want to create a function in LESS, CSS.
The function is supposed to be executed in this:

```
.col{
    .run-the-function();
    }
```

the problem is: I want the function to affect every third child for example.

```
.test(@columns, @top-margin, @right-margin){
&:nth-child(@columns * n + 0 ){

}
}
```

SUMMARY:
When the functions is beeing executed, every third, second, fourth element or whatever you set, that element will get a red border.

Do you have any ideas? is this even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work

```
.test(@columns, @top-margin, @right-margin){
    &:nth-child(@{columns}n){

    }
}
```

For more info on nth child [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)

Comment: Hmm... Why you use @columns two times, isn't it enought with (@columns * n)?

I don't think it like the asterix: *
Because my program mark it as red like it's a error at the asterix
And I get:

ParseError: Unrecognised input in

so I think the * doesn't work there :/

Comment: it's the times sign, LESS probably uses something else for that then or wrap it in math or whatever. If you just do columns * n then it will return 0, when n starts at 0.

Comment: @user256631 I have edited the answer to correct the multiplication part

Answer (score 0):

This works...

The output is alternating rows based on various "nth" values.
I will post an image here shortly.

Mark-up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/test.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <div class="alt-rows every-3rd">
      <div>Test 1</div>
      <div>Test 2</div>
      <div>Test 3</div>
      <div>Test 4</div>
      <div>Test 5</div>
      <div>Test 6</div>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="alt-rows every-2nd">
      <div>Test 1</div>
      <div>Test 2</div>
      <div>Test 3</div>
      <div>Test 4</div>
      <div>Test 5</div>
      <div>Test 6</div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Less:

```
@bg: white;
@alt-bg: gray;

.altRows(@nth-row) {
   background-color: @bg;
   div:nth-child(@{nth-row}n+1) {
      background-color: @alt-bg;
   }
}   

.alt-rows {
   &.every-2nd {
      .altRows(2);
   }

   &.every-3rd {
      .altRows(3);
   }
}
```

Comment: I was also able to make the Less completely DRY by using a loop. This gets rid of the hard-coded "every-2nd" and "every-3rd" classes.